# The network id specified in the truffle config (4447) does not match the one returned by the network (5777)

Tags: solidity

Here my test js file

```
const ApprovalContract = artifacts.require('../../contracts/ApprovalContract.sol');

contract('ApprovalContract' function (accounts) {

    it('initiates contract', async function() {
        const contract = await ApprovalContract.deployed();
        const approver = await contract.approver.call();
        assert.equal(approver, 0x3999BA5D247c800E5Ef3d4de66618741E3675379, "approver don't match");
    });
})
```

[image: From my cmd]

Comment: What is the content of your configuration file (`truffle.js` and/or `truffle-config.js`)? Are you testing against ganache or a private network? The error message is saying your truffle configuration id doesn't matches the id returned by the network.

Comment: I testing against truffle/ganache network, and I have both 2 file, truffle.js and truffle-config.js in different location. The truffle-config.js file was just an example file when i "truffle init" and below is my truffle.js file code.  

`module.exports = {
 networks: {
  development: {
   host: "127.0.0.1",
   port: 9545,
   network_id: "*"
  }
 }
};`

truffle-config.js location: D:\Desktop\BuildDapps 2\contracts
truffle.js location: D:\Desktop\BuildDapps 2\contracts\test

Comment: I think the configuration file has to be in `D:\Desktop\BuildDapps 2\`, and you should execute truffle commands from that directory. You only need one config file in your proyect, either `truffle-config.js` or `truffle.js`.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same thing when running `truffle test`.

The reason is likely because `truffle-config.js` from `truffle unbox <package>` have network information commented out.

Thus, the `port` and `network_id` default to `4447`, which is what `truffle test` defaults to if nothing is specified in `truffle-config.js`

See:
https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/1577/files

What you will need to do is to uncomment the `networks` config in `truffle-config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
  /* <- NOTE: need to uncomment this!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    test: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"
    }
  }
  */ <- NOTE: need to uncomment this!
};
```

Answer (score 0):

delete file truffle.js

file truffle-config.js
`module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 7545,
            network_id: "*"
        }
    }
};`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i did not specify the truffle-config.js in Gananche.

Go to the setting and add correct truffle-config.js

[image]